# Blueduino Rev2 service UUID for web bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Blueduino Rev2 board that I would like to have communicating with a web app ([running the chrome bluetooth software](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web)) but I'm having trouble sorting out the service UUIDs that the web bluetooth library requires.

According to the wiki, it uses the service UUID 0xFFF0, write characteristic UUID 0xFFF1 and read characteristic UUID 0xFFF2 ([source](http://wiki.aprbrother.com/wiki/Firmware/ZeroBeacon#Features)) but when I scan for the device through the web app filtering for that service UUID it doesn't appear, but does when I remove the service UUID filter.

Code used to scan for the blueduino:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    filters: [{
        name: 'ZeroBeacon',
        services: [0xFFF0]
    }]
})
```

Does anyone know what the UUIDs are that I should be using? The documentation is quite unclear and lacking.

Answer (score 1):

If the 0xFFF0 Bluetooth Service is not advertised by the Blueduino Rev2 board, you should not include it in the "services" key. It should be in "optionalServices. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web#request_bluetooth_devices

I think your code should look like:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{ name: 'ZeroBeacon' }],
  optionalServices: [0xFFF0]
});
```